# Relationship of skew and order statistics

Tags: skewness, order-statistics

I am trying to understand an expectation that I was able to write as a linear combination of order statistics of an i.i.d. sample $F$. Specifically, the linear combination of smallest and largest order statistic $F_k$ and some functions $G$.

$$E(y)=\alpha_1 F_1(x) G_1(.) + \alpha_2 F_n(x) G_n(.)$$

I do some simulations of the above, and it seems that keeping the first two moments fixed, the skew of the distribution has impact on the result. I have not checked higher moments.

Are you aware of any results that relate the skew of a distribution to the order statistic?
There is a chance that my simulation gives the wrong idea, because a lot of things go into $G$ and I perhaps did something fishy in the $G$ functions which is influenced by skew. But, imagining $G$ as constant, I would like to either confirm or rule out that the skewedness of $F$ has an influence on $E(y)$ (and then continue as necessary).

So if, for example, it is not the case that a change in skew would have impact on $F_k$, then this would tell me where to look. On the other hand, given some $\alpha$, it would make sense to me that the skew may be important because the extend and direction of the tails seem to determine the above expectation.

Right now I am just wondering if there are any results or prior applications where people looked at the skew or even kurtosis of a distribution and related them to the order statistics?
So far I found a lot about the first two moments only.

Thank you for any input, even if I am on the completely wrong path here.